# Is it a good idea to use string constant keys to avoid magic string keys?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My idea is to avoid magic string keys in my Asp.Net MVC application.
To do so, I want to create string constant keys to be shared in the application.

For example, I can write `TempData[MyConst.Message]` instead of `TempData["Message"]`.

```
public class MyConst
{
    public const string Message = "Message";
}
```

My questions are: Is it a good idea to do this way?

Comment: This is exactly what I do. I put the constant on the class that will be stored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of custom classes put your strings in a **resx** file. VS will generate a class for you and it will be easier for you to translate them into a different language in the future should the need arise.

There is nothing specific you need to do for MVC.
Take a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f(v=vs.80).aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917414

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx

For 'internal' usage I would prefer **Enums** over strings.

Comment: If the strings are displayed to the end user, then do this. However it looks like he's using them internally as Dictionary keys, in which case it's probably better to do what he's described - manually create static string constants in an abstract class.